# interface builder : make the view the same size as the iphone, to know exactly what constraints to add?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

is there a way to have the view from interface builder in Xcode, be the same size as the iphone we use to test the app? The size of the viewcontroller seems to be 600*600. So when I move a UILabel somewhere to the left for example, it will be placed as if it was on the right on my iphone. Which is not easy to set the right constraints.

Do you have some tips to manipulate the items and place them easily? For now, I just align the item with the center point, and move it little by little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is because of Apple's emphasis of size classes. It looks like a rectangle because whenever you are adding constraints and views, they'll be applied to every size class (i.e. horizontal/compact, vertical/compact, etc).

In english, it means it's applying those changes to run as such on any device.

To create constraints and views for just one size, you'll want to edit the size class you are working with. At the bottom of Xcode where it says "**wAny hAny**", click that and you can set what device you want to work with:

[image]

The whole idea of this is adaptive design, and I've got a post explaining it in more detail [here.](http://bit.ly/adaptivedesignios8)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that there is no one correct size for the iphone screen because there are so many different screen sizes. You can set the view size to anything you want in interface builder by clicking on the view and going to simulated metrics -> size but what you really want is [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) so that your views fit properly on every device.